# Django FBV's "render_to_response" equivalent in Class-Based-View?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am now in the process of converting all my Django Function-based-views in to Class-based-views...

So this is my original code:

**views.py**

```
def search(request):        
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']

        if q:
            result = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)

    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'result': result
    })

    return render_to_response('search.html', variables)
```

I am simply trying to switch this to CBV just for the purpose of practicing CBV...

This is what I have so far:

**views.py**

```
class PostSearch(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if q:
            data = {
                'result': Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
            }

            return self.render_to_response(data)
```

I thought this would work just fine, since it is a very simple code. However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: The view app_blog.views.PostSearch didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

So I guess the "render_to_response" works completely different in CBV...

What is the correct way to convert my original code into CBV??

Thanks :(((

Comment: i think `render_to_response` depreciated and old format. use `render` instead

Answer (score 8):

```
class PostSearch(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostSearch, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if q:
            context['result'] = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
        return context
```

Comment: +1 for overriding `get_context_data` rather than `get`, but you don't define `q`...

Comment: Thanks, but why is overriding "get_context_data" better than overriding "get"?? Is there any particular reason???

Comment: Yes, because you need to add stuff to the context, and that's what this function does.

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
class PostSearch(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = request.GET.get('q')
        if q:
            data = {
                'result': Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
            }

            return render(request,self.template_name,data)
        return HttpResponse('Please type a search query')
```